# Calculate (next day) date for messages posted after 16:00

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| msg_id  | user_id | _date      | _time    | count_for  |
+-------------------+------------+----------+------------+
|   1     | 1       | 2011-01-22 | 06:23:11 | 2011-01-22 |
|   2     | 1       | 2011-01-23 | 16:17:03 | 2011-01-24 |
|   3     | 1       | 2011-01-23 | 17:05:45 | 2011-01-24 |
|   4     | 2       | 2011-01-24 | 06:58:13 | 2011-01-24 |
|   5     | 2       | 2011-01-24 | 15:59:32 | 2011-01-24 |
|   6     | 3       | 2011-01-25 | 13:45:00 | ...        |
|   7     | 3       | 2011-01-26 | 13:22:34 | ...        |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+------------+
```

I want to count the number of messages per day, but messages after 16:00 this day have to count for the next day:
 - msg 1 is written before 16:00 on `2011-01-22`, so count_for is (same day) `2011-01-22`
 - msg 2 is written after 16:00 on `2011-01-23`, so count_for is (next day) `2011-01-24`

Obviously, I did the first 5 manually. My question is: with what query can I perform this operation automatically (in MySQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT count(msg_id), if(_time >= '16:00:00', _date + INTERVAL 1 DAY, _date) AS effective_date
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY effective_date
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I really meant with what update query can I insert the dates into count_for :-) I need to later on export all this to Excell for someone elkse to perform stuff with. Would that then be `UPDATE messages SET count_for = if(_time >= '16:00:00', _date + INTERVAL 1 DAY, _date)`?

Comment: Ah. just turn it into an UPDATE query instead, `UPDATE yourtable SET count_for=if(....)`

Comment: I think you should be in the habit of using CASE instead of IF, since CASE is part of the SQL standard, and hence works on other databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(_time < '16:00:00', _date, ADDDATE(_date, 1)) AS d, COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY d
```